# Error: jQuery.dialogExtend Error : Only jQuery UI Dialog element is accepted

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i using jquery.dialogextend.js 2.0.0, jquery.min.js and jquery-ui.min.js.

same function working in other module.

my jquery dialog js is below:

```
$(function(){

    ////auto open dialog/////////////       
        //check cookie
        if( document.cookie.indexOf( "nce=true" ) < 0 ) {

        //dialog options
        var dialogOptions = {
            "title" : "title",
            "open" : function () {
                $("#open").prop("disabled",true);
                $(this).load('pop.php');
                $(this).parent().css('opacity', 0.4);
                $(this).parent().hover( function () { 
                    $(this).css('opacity', 0.9); 
                }, function (event) { 
                    $(this).css('opacity', 0.4); 
                });  
            },
            "width" : 370,
            "height" : 250,
            "dialogClass": 'dlgfixed',
            "position" : ['right bottom'], 
            "modal" : false,
            "autoOpen": true,
            "closeOnEscape" : true,
            "draggable" : true,
            "close" : function(){ 
                $(this).remove(); 
                document.cookie = "Once=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
                $("#open").prop("disabled",false);
            }
        };

        var dialogExtendOptions = {
                       "closable" : true,
                       "maximizable" : true,
                       "minimizable" : true,
     };
        // open dialog
        $("<div><div />").dialog(dialogOptions).dialogExtend(dialogExtendOptions);

  }
});
```

but i got below error :

```
Error: jQuery.dialogExtend Error : Only jQuery UI Dialog element is accepted
```

Comment: What versions of jQuery and jQueryUI are you using?

Comment: jQuery UI - v1.8.21 and jquery v1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a compatibility issue. If you take a look at [the readme for dialogextend's 2.0.0 version](https://github.com/ROMB/jquery-dialogextend/blob/c0831f079cb46e2e4513a16b7415fce5505da7b7/README.md):

### Compatible

- jQuery 1.9.1
- jQueryUI 1.10.2

It should work if you just swap out the jquery-ui.js file with the 1.10 version. However, I recommend updating all three libraries to the latest versions (1.11, 1.11, 2.0.4), that *hopefully should* fix your issue without any additional effort. If not, try debugging to localize the source of that exception